# ASP.NET MVC normal edit form with upload (and validation) using jQuery UI Modal

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a form that resides inside a jQuery UI dialog, the form have some fields such as first, last name, etc... and also allow file upload. I can't use Ajax.BeginForm() since ajax doesn't allow upload (or does it?), so I have to use the regular Html.BeginForm() for my form to call my ActionResult. But I need to do some validation on the server and displays the response within that form, or displays a message if the form successfully posted. How do I displays the message in that jQuery UI modal dialog?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Ajax.BeginForm` which is tied to the **crappy** Microsoft Ajax library use a normal `Html.BeginForm` with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the excellent [jQuery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin which allows you to ajaxify forms ([even forms that contain file upload fields](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload)).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, using regular Html.BeginForm with jQuery.form solved the problem! Pretty cool stuffs, I was having problem with getting a json response from my ActionResult so I went with just a comma delimited string.